# Getting strange error while downloading .xlsx file with wget

Tags: python-3.x, exception, wget

I use **Jupyter Notebook on Win10 Home (RU)**. So,
I try to download `.xlsx` file and to name it *'data_3_course.xlsx'* the same time - with that code:

```
!wget  -O 'data_3_course.xlsx' -q 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/ysxs5srafoyxknb/_data_3_course.xlsx?dl=1'
```

But I get a very strange  exception\error (in pink colour):

```
"wget" Ґ пў«пҐвбп ўгваҐҐ© Ё«Ё ўҐиҐ©
Є®¬ ¤®©, ЁбЇ®«пҐ¬®© Їа®Ја ¬¬®© Ё«Ё Ї ЄҐвл¬ д ©«®¬.
```

=

```
"wget" it is not an internal or external
command, an executable program, or a batch file
```

Well, **some useful info**:  `wget-3.2` module is imported - `pip list` find it [in this pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0U7i.png), the link works (file is downloaded manually).
How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*get a very strange exception\error*

You have problems with encoding, in such case I use [2cyr.com](https://2cyr.com/decode/?lang=en) which allowed to recover that it should be

```
"wget" е является вутреей или вешей
ком дой, исполяемой прогр ммой или п кетым ф йлом.
```

which as far as I can say is leglible Russian text.

*wget-3.2 module is imported - pip list find it in this pic, the link works (file is downloaded manually). How to fix it?*

You are probably mistaking two different wgets - [GNU wget](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) which can be used as `wget` in terminal and [wget](https://pypi.org/project/wget/) which is python's external module. If you want to use second from terminal you should be compliant with described **Usage**, i.e. to download http://www.example.com/ as `example.html` do

```
python -m wget -o example.html http://www.example.com/
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I understood what is happenig in code)) I added one more answer with my own observations, working code and your your links (hope you will not mind it :)

Answer (score 0):

So with a very important notice frow @Daweo **I got a good lesson:**

(JN = Jupyter Notebook)

1. If I want to download file with `GNU wget`(read about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget))
   in JN, I should place `wget.exe` in  PATH-directory and restart JN;
   the code will be:

   ```
   !wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/ysxs5srafoyxknb/_data_3_course.xlsx?dl=1 -O data_3_course_copy2.xlsx
   ```

   **In terminal** the code is the same without '**!**'.
2. If I want to download file with python `wget` module (read about it
   [here](https://pypi.org/project/wget/)) in JN:

   ```
   pip install wget
   import wget
   url = 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/ysxs5srafoyxknb/_data_3_course.xlsx?dl=1'

   wget.download(url, '/Users/ASUS/Downloads/data_3_course_copy.xlsx')
   ```

   **In  terminal** it the code will look like @Daweo wrote :)